# Concat values in postgresql without null values

Tags: postgresql

I trying to concatenating the four-column to one column. i using coalease for replacing null as space but while concatenating. if the particular column has null value then i dont need spaces in concatenated results

```
UPDATE vt_pc_incremental_gold_contact SET "Concatenated Phone Number" = 
trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Country Code",'')||' '||trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Area Code",''))||' '||trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Number",''))
||' '||trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Extension",'')));
```

I need results like this

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace()` function to replace those double `spaces`.

```
UPDATE vt_pc_incremental_gold_contact SET "Concatenated Phone Number" = 
replace(trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Country Code",'')||' '||trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Area Code",''))||' '||trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Number",''))
||' '||trim(coalesce("Contact Phone Extension",''))), '  ', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

User "concat_ws". It will solve your problem.

```
UPDATE vt_pc_incremental_gold_contact SET "Concatenated Phone Number" = 
concat_ws(' ',trim("Contact Phone Country Code")
   ,trim("Contact Phone Area Code"),trim("Contact Phone Number"),trim("Contact Phone Extension"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat_ws()` this will properly deal with empty strings and spaces

```
UPDATE vt_pc_incremental_gold_contact 
  SET "Concatenated Phone Number" = concat_ws(' ', "Contact Phone Country Code", "Contact Phone Area Code", "Contact Phone Number", "Contact Phone Extension");
```